# Knockout.js subscribe to observable element inside observable array

Tags: knockout.js, observable, subscribe

js My Course do not subscribe to observable array when change. Console logs do not shows. I don't know how to fix it. Any idea?

```js
class Course {
  constructor(data) {
    this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    this.lecturer = ko.observable(data.lecturer);
    this.name.subscribe(function(newName) {
      console.log(newName);
    });
    this.lecturer.subscribe(function(newLecturer) {
      console.log(newLecturer);
    });
  }
}

function ProtoModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.courses = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.addCourse = function() {
    const newCourse = new Course({
      name: this.newCourseNameText(),
      lecturer: this.newCourseLecturerText()
    });
    self.courses.push(ko.mapping.toJS(newCourse));
    self.newCourseNameText("");
    self.newCourseLecturerText("");
  };
}

var model = new ProtoModel();

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Course constructor, you create completely new observable and then assign only value from old observable into it. And you subscribe to this new observable.

Then, after creation you're trying to change your 'old' observable and if you subscribe to its changes - you will see them. But, observables created in newCourse keep untouched.

Try to replace

```
self.newCourseNameText("");
self.newCourseLecturerText("");
```

with

```
self.newCourse.name("");
self.newCourse.lecturer("");
```

Comment: I create new course from course constructor. 
newCourseNameText is bind to clean input and when i type and press button with data-bind="click: addCourse" , then i push this course to observable array. Finally I clean this inputs after submit. 

but i have courses array in table with inputs, and when i edit specific course i want to subscribe it, but it didnt work

Comment: can you explain it better??, I don't get it.

Comment: can you pls add code where you do change those vars ? is it in html or js?

Comment: btw, when you doing `self.courses.push(ko.mapping.toJS(newCourse));` you push into observable array json-copy of your newCourse, not the object with observables itselt. So, if your edit some course later in this array it will not affect original subscription, because it's a different object with no observables

Comment: Here is my github repo: https://github.com/Szalbik/E-Proto-Front/blob/master/script.js

Comment: And this is html: https://github.com/Szalbik/E-Proto-Front/blob/master/index.html

Comment: on this next code part `axios
        .post(`${apiSerwer}/courses`, ko.mapping.toJS(newCourse))
        .then(function(res) {
          self.courses.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(res.data));
        });` you push to array new object created by mapping plugin, but it's not  the newCourse object, it's different one

Comment: So how i should create new object and push it to array? I thought that im doing it good.

Comment: self.addCourse = function() {
      const newCourse = new Course({
        name: this.newCourseNameText(),
        lecturer: this.newCourseLecturerText()
      });

      axios
        .post(`${apiSerwer}/courses`, ko.mapping.toJS(newCourse))
        .then(function(res) {
         newCourse.id = res.data.id;
          self.courses.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(newCourse));
        });

      self.newCourseNameText("");
      self.newCourseLecturerText("");
    };

Comment: i've created jfiddle. There you can see 3 example how this will work. There're a lot of other way - that's just to give you direction http://jsfiddle.net/oshumelyuk/dc86pr0z/9/